# Java loop through all letters of the alphabet plus '

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to creat a loop that goes through all the alphabet from a to z, but then after z, I want it to try the apostrophe '. 
Can I do that all in one loop?
What I have now:

```
  for(char ch = 'a' ; ch <= 'z' ; ++ch ){
      //do something with ch
 }
```

for example, let's say I want to take the word "Hi" and turn it into: 
Hia, 
Hib, 
Hic, 
Hid, 
...
Hix, 
Hiy, 
Hiz, 
Hi'

Can this be done?

Comment: What's stopping you from trying it yourself to find out?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do it. ++ch will go sequentially from a to z. adding a ' is not a sequential operation, so it's kind of out of the structure of a for loop.

Comment: Then you've answered your own question, haven't you? If the `'` is not sequentially directly after `'z'`, then you can't do it in a single for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. One solution: iterate from `0` to `27` (exclusive). For every `i` less than `26` use `'a' + i` when you get to `26` change the value to a `'`. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    char ch = (char) ('a' + i);
    if (i == 26) {
        ch = '\'';
    }
    System.out.printf("Hi%c%n", ch);
}
```

Another way you could do it, build a `String` of suffix characters and iterate that. Like,

```
String chars = "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz'";
for (char ch : chars.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.printf("Hi%c%n", ch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct. But the character array missing character 'n' which took me some time to debug. I am posting this as answer as I could not edit the above one. If you are copy pasting please take the below array:

```
String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for (char ch : chars.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.printf("Hi%c%n", ch);
}
```